# is there any builtin method in mongodb to update an array inside of a mongodb document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

What i actually want to do is to add on to an array inside a mongodb document in such a way that the original array is intact,but a new array item has been added much like the spread operator

```
[...oldarray,additional_Array_item]
```

How to achieve this in mongodb, is there an builtin function in mongodb for this, if not, then what would be the most optimistic option to achieve this task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [$push-update operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)

`Example from the documentation` It adds 89 to the scores array. Similarly you can add an object also.

```
db.students.update(
   { _id: 1 },
   { $push: { scores: 89 } }
)
```